# creando stored procedure

Tags: sql

Estoy intentando crear un stored procedure en mysql, para que inserte datos en una tabla llamada cliente con las columnas :(Id_Cliente,
Nombre_cliente,
Sexo,
DNI,
telefono,
Ciudad_de_residencia,
Direccion).

Me crea la funcion pero cuando la ejecuto me da el siguiente error:Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'N_Ciudada_de_residencia' in 'field list'

````
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_INSERTAR_DATO (
IN N_Id_Cliente int,
IN N_Nombre_cliente VARCHAR (50),
IN N_Sexo enum ('Masculino','Femenino'),
IN N_DNI int,
IN N_telefono varchar (25) ,
IN N_Ciudad_de_residencia char(40),
IN N_Direccion varchar (60))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO cliente (
Id_Cliente,
Nombre_cliente,
Sexo,
DNI,
telefono,
Ciudad_de_residencia,
Direccion
)
VALUES (
N_Id_Cliente,
N_Nombre_cliente,
N_Sexo,
N_DNI,
N_TELEFONO,
N_Ciudada_de_residencia,
N_DIRECCION
);
END//
DELIMITER ;  ```
````

Comment: A ver la tabla? 

Comment: Hay que leer los mensajes de error... Unknown column 'N_Ciudada_de_residencia': claro, ¡porque el parámetro se llama `N_Ciudad_de_residencia`!